# How to customize a UITableView cell when in "Confirm to Delete" state and the table is in Edit Mode

Tags: ios

However I would like to customize the cell when the users touch the icon on the row left in order to display the Delete button. And when he eventually cancel the delete operation (the cell should come back to the previous state).

The table is in the Edit Mode. Therefore the delegate methods are not invoked. (I've tried).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

See third row in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle those events in the cell itself (for that you will need to subclass UITableViewCell). When cell changes its editing state the following methods will be called:

```
-willTransitionToState:
-didTransitionToState:
```

Where state parameter is bitmask specifying which UI elements are/will be visible in given cell.

Comment: Thanks they are invoked when the left button is touched indeed. But not if I touch elsewhere and the operation is cancel. In other terms I need a method where to restore the previous cell state.

Comment: @Patrick, I made sample project and I get those methods called in every situation...May be you can provide more details about your particular case?

Comment: Weird, they are not invoked when I touch another row in the tableview (and I see the row Delete button to disappear). The table is in 'Editing mode' (did you try with this setting on?).

Comment: I've just subclassed UITableViewCell and added those methods there. The table is added to the view with interface builder. Let me know what kind of information I can provide you.

Comment: Frankly, I can't think of anything from the top of my head... Try to check what can be different in your implementation from default behavior

Comment: So it works for you, in editing mode. The method are called both when the left button is touched and the cell enters in "Delete confirmation" mode, and when another cell is selected and the cell leaves such mode.

Comment: I uploaded sample project to github: https://github.com/vlk/CellStateTest, unless I misunderstood something it works fine for me in all cases

Comment: I see where the issue is. It works for me in iOS6, but I'm currently developing in iOS7 beta and it is probably buggy. Sorry for the inconvenient. I've accepted your answer.